# Localhost:3000 not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

So I have been working on CRA and NextJS projects for the last 5-6 months and it works every time but since yesterday, I have no idea what has happened but every time I run my project I cannot access it at localhost:3000.

This message is displayed usually when a NextJS app starts -

```
started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

Localhost gives me the following - [image]

However when I go to `0.0.0.0:3000` , I'm able to access my application normally.

I have no idea what has happened,

My suspicion is the PHP live server extension in VS Code, I accidentally clicked on it and my localhost hasn't been working since. I have since uninstalled and removed PHP Live server extension, flushed my dns, cleared my cache but no changes yet.

I have tried multiple different projects and even a fresh CRA install to diagnose and the problem persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: did u try to kill the process by port ?

Comment: I'm not sure, what process do I try to kill?

Comment: what is your os ?

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Comment: using the terminal 

try this  `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000`

you will get a process id 
after that try 
`kill -QUIT pid`

Comment: Thank you so much, I did some search regarding that command and found `lsof -i tcp:3000` which showed me the PHP server that was running exactly. This has been fixed now thank you.